# Finding PHP latest release version

Tags: php

I would like to be able to display in the application if it's running latest PHP version by comparing return of `phpversion()` with the latest from http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php - can I check this in a better way than parsing the mentioned URL's HTML?

Comment: use curl to get the page ( or file_get_contents ), load into DOMDocument, create an xpath query to find the node and return the value.... simples!

Comment: @RamRaider > you're describing "parsing HTML", which the OP doesn't want...

Comment: See my updated answer, I found a simple to use, official supported solution

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

When visiting http://www.php.net/releases, I noticed that on the right panel, it says:

> **Want a PHP serialized list of the PHP releases?**
>
> Add `?serialize` to the url
> Only want PHP 5 releases? `&version=5`
> The last 3? `&max=3`
>
> **Want a JSON list of the PHP releases?**
>
> Add `?json` to the url
> Only want PHP 5 releases? `&version=5`
> The last 3? `&max=3`

So whether you'd rather use a PHP serialized version or JSON, you might use http://www.php.net/releases?serialize or http://www.php.net/releases?json

If you want to only see Version 5.x.x, you could use:

http://www.php.net/releases?json&version=5 (If you'd like to use JSON, otherwise replace `json` with `serialize`)

**Original Answer** (Critical, see Nannes comment)

Parsing the HTML structure is of course a bad idea, since the structure of the tags could change when a new homepage of php.net is introduced.

While searching for a solution, I came across this Atom feed: http://php.net/releases/feed.php

Since this is a Atom feed, the strucutre will not change, as it is defined by a standard **1]**. You can then use PHP's default XML functions **2]** to parse `feed > entry:first-child > php:version` (CSS-Syntax for demonstration purpose. `:first-child` is the first child selector, `>` the direct child selector) and then use PHP's `version_compare` **3]**.

More information:

- **1]** [Atom standard (RFC 4287)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287)
- **2]** [PHP XML functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)
- **3]** [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Comment: This seems to be the best option at the moment.

Comment: The structure could of course change, but it's less likely. What is a possible issue here is that there's no guarantee that the first child is the highest version, as there are release for all supported versions in there. So you can either check all entries and get the highest of the version to check against, or (maybe better?) only compare against the major version you're runnen, e.g.: only check 5.5.x against 5.5.? etc. (but you should add an "is it still supported" check then, that might be harder)

Comment: @Nanne First, the structure will not change, since it is validated against the `xmlns` to `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`, which is an official standard (see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4287 for more information). Second, you are right that this could lead to errors. But your approach should fix the problem. I will think about it and update my answer accordingly. Thank you for your objection

Comment: I updated my answer, since I found a much better solution using PHP's serialize or JSON officially offered by php.net

Comment: `?serialize` and `?json` options. Nice! That's a sure winner. Great work :)

Comment: @CharlyDelta well, obviously the structure as a feed won't change, but there is nothing in the atom standard that forces any feed to have, for instance, any field called "php:version". That would be somewhat weird, no? But it is a moot point as the change of it changing is way low of course

Comment: With structure, I was reffering to `feed > entry:first-child`. They won't change it, as the standard does not support this. Every Atom reader wouldn't accept a feed that does not conform to the standard. Yes, they could change the `php:version` node, but this is, like you said, very unlikely, since it is perfectly short and the name of the node is self-explaining. And even if they would, it would just require to change a line of code to make it working again. Parsing a HTML-structure on the other hand, could lead to much trouble since the tag-structure could change dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = @file_get_contents('https://www.php.net/releases/?json');
$data = @json_decode($data, true);
$data = current($data);
echo 'Latest version: ' . $data['version'];
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

This is something of a proof-of-concept so YMMV. But you assuming you have `curl` available, you could query the GitHub API, to retrieve, filter and sort the latest tags from the [GitHub PHP Mirror](https://github.com/php/php-src). Authentication is not required.

Alternatively you could retrieve all branches, but a cursory glance suggests the latest versions are tagged.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
<?php

$endpoint  = 'https://api.github.com/repos/php/php-src/tags';
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$json = curl_exec($curl);
$code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

if (200 !== $code) {
    throw new RuntimeException('HTTP response code %d encountered', $code);
}

$data = json_decode($json, true);
$tags = array_column($data, 'name');

// exclude all RC/alpha/beta and any tag not starting with php-*
$filtered = preg_grep('/^php-\d+.\d+.\d+$/', $tags);
rsort($filtered, SORT_NATURAL);

var_dump($filtered);
```

This yields something like:

```
array(10) {
  [0] =>
  string(10) "php-5.6.12"
  [1] =>
  string(10) "php-5.6.11"
  [2] =>
  string(10) "php-5.6.10"
  [3] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.9"
  [4] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.8"
  [5] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.7"
  [6] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.6"
  [7] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.5"
  [8] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.4"
  [9] =>
  string(9) "php-5.6.3"
}
```

Note that I am explicitly setting a User Agent because GitHub won't return a `200` response without one.

Once you have this, you can use it however you wish; e.g:

```
$latest = array_shift($filtered);
printf('The latest version of PHP is %s. You are using %s', $latest, phpversion());
```

> The latest version of PHP is php-5.6.12. You are using 5.6.9

Hope this helps :)